# Backbone override sync and update model

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, parse-platform

I wrote the function below to update a model but It needs an access-token so I thought to override sync function but I have always this error:

```
 PUT https://api.parse.com/1/users/ZT0w7QdYvk 400 (Bad Request)
```

so I think maybe sync is not correctly override or maybe some other error.

```
updateUser: function(){

      var sync = Backbone.sync;
      var parseSessionToken = window.localStorage.getItem('parseSessionToken');
      Backbone.sync = function(method, model, options) {
           options.beforeSend = function(xhr) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Parse-Application-Id', 'uR2Omi3B**ed9thVESad');
            xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Parse-REST-API-Key', 'GbwUqq**Fxzbd1tFCXje');
            xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Parse-Session-Token', parseSessionToken);
        };


        sync(method, model, options);

          }









    var targa = $('#targa').val();
    var auto = $('#auto').val();


    var users = new Utenti();

    users.fetch({
     success: function () {

    var user = users.get( window.localStorage.getItem('parseId'));
    console.log(targa);
    user.set({'targa': targa,'auto':auto});
    console.log(user);
    user.save();


        }
      });




         },
```

Comment: You can override `sync` on a per-model/collection basis. I wouldn't override the base Backbone.sync.

Comment: @UziKilon how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can override sync on a per-model/collection basis. I wouldn't override the base `Backbone.sync`:

```
var MyModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
  sync: function (method, model, options) {
    options.header = _.extend(options.header || {}, {
      'X-Parse-Application-Id': 'uR2Omi3B**ed9thVESad',
      'X-Parse-REST-API-Key': 'GbwUqq**Fxzbd1tFCXje',
      'X-Parse-Session-Token': parseSessionToken
    });
    return Backbone.Model.prototype.sync.call(this, method, model, options);
  }
});
```